# Check if an array has any element in another array

Tags: ruby, literals

I have two arrays:

```
one = ["2cndb", "7bndb", "14accdb", "5ggdb"]
two = [["2cndb", "alive"], ["14accdb", "alive"], ["5ggdb", "not alive"]]
```

I want to check if each sub-array in `two` contains any element of `one`. When it does, I want to add an element `"yes"` to the sub-array, `"no"` otherwise.

My code is:

```
two.each do |item|
if (one.include?('item[0]'))
        item.push("yes")
    else
        item.push("no")
    end
end
```

and I get

```
two = [["2cndb", "alive", "no"], ["14accdb", "alive", "no"], ["5ggdb", "not alive", "no"]]
```

But `"2cndb"`, `"14accdb"`, `"5ggdb"` are present in `one`. Can You suggest where the problem is?

Comment: `item[0]` without quotes.

Comment: `'item[0]'` is not `item[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use just `item[0]` without quotes. But you said that you want to check *all values* in subarrays: in this case your solution will still wrong, so possible solution is:

```
one = ["2cndb", "7bndb", "14accdb", "5ggdb"]
two = [["2cndb", "alive"], ["14accdb", "alive"], 
       ["5ggdb", "not alive"], ["foo", "bar"]]
two.map { |e| e + [(one & e).empty? ? 'no'  : 'yes']}
#=> [["2cndb", "alive", "yes"], ["14accdb", "alive", "yes"],
#    ["5ggdb", "not alive", "yes"], ["foo", "bar", "no"]]
```